# RxJSを読み込むとTypeErrorが起きてしまう。

Tags: javascript, rx-javascript

JavaScriptで`RxJS/dist/rx.all.min.js`を読み込むと `TypeError: a is null` が起きてしまいます。なぜ起きてしまうのでしょうか?

下記が実際のコードです。
ブラウザは Firefox 37を使っています。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="RxJS/dist/rx.all.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <div id="divHello">
            Hello
        </div>
        <script>
            var divHello = document.querySelector("divHello");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 似たようなコードをjsfiddleで試した限りでは再現しませんでした。RxJSのバージョン（今いくつなのかわかりませんが）を変えたり、cdnjsなどから読み込んでも同じでしょうか？querySelectorを取り除くとどうなりますか？ http://jsfiddle.net/favg3ypg/3/

Comment: querySelectorに渡す文字列を"#devHello"に変更したら解決しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelector` に渡す文字列を `#devHello` に変更したら解決しました。

---

*この投稿は [@KiYugadgeter さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9530/rxjs%e3%82%92%e8%aa%ad%e3%81%bf%e8%be%bc%e3%82%80%e3%81%a8typeerror%e3%81%8c%e8%b5%b7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%a6%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%86#comment8667_9530) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*